# Problems downloading rpm files $ARCH in url

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm

I have already installed CentOS 8 on a VMware... When i execute this command:

```
yum search epel
```

I get this messages

```
HEL 8 - RPMforge.net - dag                     5.4  B/s | 169  B     00:31    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rpmforge':
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirrors.neterra.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 31.13.223.131)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/dag/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 129.102.1.37)
  - Status code: 404 for http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 147.52.159.12)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.bacloud.com/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 91.216.163.60)
  - Status code: 404 for http://merlin.fit.vutbr.cz/mirrors/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 147.229.176.19)
  - Status code: 404 for http://kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 123.255.202.74)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror1.hs-esslingen.de/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 129.143.116.10)
  - Status code: 404 for https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 101.6.8.193)
  - Status code: 404 for http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 81.194.43.155)
  - Status code: 404 for http://repoforge.ip-connect.vn.ua/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 91.236.251.14)
  - Status code: 404 for http://ftp.fi.muni.cz/pub/linux/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 147.251.48.205)
  - Status code: 404 for http://ftp.is.co.za/mirror/ftp.rpmforge.net/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 196.4.160.12)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.as24220.net/pub/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 116.66.162.254)
  - Status code: 404 for http://ftp.surfsara.nl/pub/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 145.100.12.227)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.poliwangi.ac.id/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 103.109.210.14)
  - Status code: 404 for http://repoforge.mirror.wearetriple.com/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 93.187.10.106)
  - Status code: 404 for http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 145.220.21.40)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.zetup.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 109.205.222.4)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.awanti.com/rpmforge/dag/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 91.190.113.114)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirrors.netix.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 87.121.121.2)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 204.99.128.20)
  - Status code: 404 for http://repoforge.spinellicreations.com/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 98.118.131.16)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.teklinks.com/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 207.223.121.100)
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirrors.nav.ro/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 5.154.224.26)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rpmforge': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

I don't know why I'm getting the string "$ARCH" in all URLs, when i change this string manually with the "x86_64" I get http status code 200.

Please, what shoul I do?

Comment: Looks like a malformed repo in /etc/yum /etc/yum/repos.d

Answer (score 0):

Malformed repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/

It should not be $ARCH but $basearch.